# play-slick scala many to many

Tags: sql, scala, many-to-many, slick

I have an endpoint lets say /order/ where i can send json object(my order), which contains some products etc, so my problem is i have to first save the order and wait for the order id back from the db and then save my products with this new order id( we are talking many to many relation thats why theres another table)

Consider this controller method

```
def postOrder = Action(parse.json[OrderRest]) { req => {

    Created(Json.toJson(manageOrderService.insertOrder(req.body)))
  }
}
```

this is how my repo methods look like

```
  def addOrder(order: Order) = db.run {
    (orders returning orders) += order
  }
```

how can i chain  db.runs to first insert order, get order id and then insert my products with this order id i just got?

im thinking about putting some service between my controller and repo, and managing those actions there, but i have no idea where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `for` to chain database operations. Here is an example of adding a table to a db by adding a header row to represent the table and then adding the data rows. In this case it is a simple table containing `(age, value)`.

```
/** Add a new table to the database */
def addTable(name: String, table: Seq[(Int, Int)]) = {
  val action = for {
    key <- (Headers returning Headers.map(_.tableId)) += HeadersRow(0, name)
    _ <- Values ++= table.map { case (age, value) => ValuesRow(key, age, value) }
  } yield key

  db.run(action.transactionally)
}
```

This is cut down from the working code, but it should give the idea of how to do what you want. The first `for` statement would generate the order id and then the second statement would add the order with that order id.

This is done `transactionally` so that the new order will not be created unless the order data is valid (in database terms).